# Android relaunching Timers after they are canceled

Tags: android, timer, android-asynctask

I have a timer in my application that launches an AsyncTask every 15 secs.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

public void AsynchTaskTimer() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    TimerTask timertask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        new updateGPSTask().execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timertask, 0, 15000); // execute in every 15sec
}
```

This is launched from the `onCreate()` method.

When I call another activity I need to cancel this timer, which I did using `timer.cancel()` on my `onPause()` method in my Main Activity.

Now when I return to the Main Activity I need to restart the timer. I tried relaunching the `AsynchTaskTimer()` in the `onRestart()` method, but I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer was canceled`.

How do I restart my timer?

Comment: set the timer as null in onpause and reinsiate it like timer = new Timer(); and launch it as the old hashed object was canceled it cant be restarted unless reinitiated to a new one

Comment: why are you using handler and timer together ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try using :

```
public void AsynchTaskTimer() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    TimerTask timertask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        new updateGPSTask().execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer = new Timer(); //This is new
    timer.schedule(timertask, 0, 15000); // execute in every 15sec
    }
```

By using this you can again allocate the memory to Timer and start it AFAIK.

Comment: thank you, this works, combined with cancelling the timer in the `onPause()`method!

Comment: only thing i couldnt get yet is what does the second parameter of the schedule() method does?
 timer.schedule(timertask, 0, 15000), in this example what does the 0 signifies

Answer (score 17):

So what says docs about **cancel()** method:

> Note that calling this method from within the run method of a
>   repeating timer task absolutely guarantees that the timer task will
>   not run again.

It means that if you once cancel() Timer you can't to run it again. You need to create new instance of Timer, for example in [`onResume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) method if you want to run it again.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   // intialise new instance of Timer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `TimerTask`, you can move your code (which is used to update GPS) to a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). I think it's better. You can call [`startService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) in `onCreate()` and [`stopService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29) in `onDestroy()`. Note that services run on main UI thread, so make sure to avoid of [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) in your GPS updater task.

Comment: this was my initial approach, but for some reason my Service didn't start.. Since this is just for a proof of concept it doesn't really matter, but it is on my TODO list if it ever develops into a real thing!